# Plotting averaged values against baseline, run linear regression

Tags: r, plot, regression, average

Some data to get started:

```
ID <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C","C")
SampleSection <- c("Base", "First", "Second","Second","Base","First","First","Second","Base","First","First","Second","Second")
lnCort <- c(7.26, 7.68, 7.73, 7.80, 7.95, 7.16, 6.88, 7.81, 7.75, 7.75, 7.40, 8.43, 7.18)
data.frame(ID,SampleSection,lnCort)
```

Some individuals have multiple "lnCort" values for "First" and "Second" SampleSections. If there are multiple measures for one individual within First or Second, I'd like to take the average of that, then create two different plots: lnCort Base on the x and lnCort [First or Second] on the y...
I can figure out the regression from there but I am having difficulty figuring out how to take the average of the data in the way I described to plot against the baseline values.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you just looking for `data <- data %>% dplyr::group_by(ID, SampleSelection) %>% dplyr::summarize(lnCort = mean(lnCort))`?

Comment: @zephryl For example: for ID A, I'd like to plot the Base lnCort value (7.26) against the mean lnCort value for First (here, just 7.68), then a separate graph with Base lnCort (7.26 for A again) against the mean lnCort value with Second (7.77 here for A). But I'd like to do this for all individuals in my data set. Some have multiple values for First and/or Second, some might not have any. Does that help clarify?

(it looks like the code you offered is giving me the overall mean of lnCort, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have two different questions -- how to aggregate multiple observations, and how to make your plots.

First, to average across multiple observations, group by `ID` and `SampleSection` and summarize using the mean of `lnCort`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df_aggregated <- df_orig %>% 
  group_by(ID, SampleSection) %>% 
  summarize(lnCort = mean(lnCort), .groups = "drop")

df_aggregated

#> # A tibble: 9 × 3
#>   ID    SampleSection lnCort
#>   <chr> <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 A     Base            7.26
#> 2 A     First           7.68
#> 3 A     Second          7.76
#> 4 B     Base            7.95
#> 5 B     First           7.02
#> 6 B     Second          7.81
#> 7 C     Base            7.75
#> 8 C     First           7.58
#> 9 C     Second          7.80
```

You can then use this dataset in your regression, e.g., `lm(lnCort ~ ordered(SampleSection), data = df_aggregated)`.

Next, one way to approach the plots is to pivot your data wider, then map `Base` to `x` and `First` or `Second` to `y` in separate plots:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df_aggr_wide <- df_aggregated %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = SampleSection, values_from = lnCort)

ggplot(df_aggr_wide, aes(Base, First)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(df_aggr_wide, aes(Base, Second)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = lm)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>